# Why the Spring Boot log contains the debug level messages?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging

In my Spring Boot application I have the following specification of logging:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web: INFO
logging.config: config/logback.xml
```

Also, in the logback.xml the level also is defined as INFO:

```
<configuration scan="false">
<appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <discriminator>
        <key>loggroup</key>
        <defaultValue>common</defaultValue>
    </discriminator>
    <sift>
        <appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>logs/myservice-${loggroup}.log</file>
    </sift>
</appender>
<logger name="com.mycompany" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="SIFT" />
</logger>
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="SIFT" />
</root>
```

Still I am getting the Debug level log message:

{"timestamp":1535034810162,"datetime":"2018-08-23T10:33:30.162-0400","hostname":"anarinsky-mbp.mycompany.local","username":"alex","level":"DEBUG","thread":"Test worker","loggername":"org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping","message":"7 request handler methods found on class com.mycompany.was.service.integration.keyvalue.KeyValueController:

Comment: try adding `debug=false` in your application properties file.

Comment: this is no valid xml file or logback configuration. The closing tag of the inner appender tag is missing and the definition of rollingPolicy and encoder as well. And the message you show seems to be an incomplete JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

You might simply add :

```
<logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="SIFT" />
</logger>
```

At the end of your `logback.xml`, just after/before the logger for `com.mycompany`.

Not 100% sure this is the one causing the problem here though. Another possibility is that for `SIFT` appender the root log level is `INFO` but there is also the default log appender that is also running in parallel and is therefore not concerned by the :

```
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="SIFT" />
</root>
```

This is my 2 cents, I might be wrong but it's worth checking this out as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration does not limit the output level,
it sets the default output level to INFO.
This can be overridden in code,
which appears to be the case.

I believe you want to setup a threshold filter.

`ThresholdFilter`
is described on the [Logback Filters Page](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html).